# bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, logging, arguments, goaccess

I have 27 000 logs file and need to parse them in one time in GoAccess. every time i run this command

```
goaccess /home/goaccess/part/2/*.log --log-format='%^ %dT%t.%^ %v %h:%^ %^ %^ %T %^ %s %^ %^ %b "%r" "%u" %k %K %^' -o /var/www/html/index.html --date-format=%Y-%m-%d --time-format=%T
```

it says

> bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

i have tried all the things suggested by chatgpt and bard still same problem.

Comment: Your error message comes from bash about an invocation of `find`. There is no _find_ command in the code you have posted.  You have to look into the code of `goaccess`. Perhaps it is invoking `find` somewhere.

Comment: [goaccess](https://goaccess.io/) claims to be written in C so I suspect your `find` problem is in some other part of your code than the line you've shown us. Post a minimal, complete script with the full error message that will contain the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Furthermore, a quick scan through the code at github reveals no invocation of `find` or `bash`. So, it extremely unlikely that the errormessage comes from `goaccess`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
find /home/goaccess/part/2/ -name \*\.log -print0 | xargs -0 -I goaccess {} --log-format='%^ %dT%t.%^ %v %h:%^ %^ %^ %T %^ %s %^ %^ %b "%r" "%u" %k %K %^' -o /var/www/html/index.html --date-format=%Y-%m-%d --time-format=%T
```

This should batch the goaccess commands into groups that fit under the arg list restriction amount, using xargs (which was specifically designed for this type of issue), and allow an arbitrary number of files to be processed. See man xargs for more details and examples.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that `.` is not a special globbing character; it doesn't require escaping.

Comment: Add `-maxdepth 1` maybe to avoid recursion in sub-directories.

Comment: No need for `xargs` here; `find ... -name '*.log' -exec goaccess {} ... +` would suffice, as well as allowing as many arguments to `goaccess` as possible in each invocation.

Comment: The author correctly states that "... need to parse them in *one time* in GoAccess.". Since goaccess should create statistics from the web log the find approach which can result in multiple calls might not yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few things.

Change into the log directory first:

```
cd /home/goaccess/part/2 && goaccess *.log --log-format='%^ %dT%t.%^ %v %h:%^ %^ %^ %T %^ %s %^ %^ %b "%r" "%u" %k %K %^' -o /var/www/html/index.html --date-format=%Y-%m-%d --time-format=%T
```

but for 27k files it is probably not enough.

If the filename is not important for your goaccess invocation (and I don't know it well enough to say if it is important) piping the log content would work:

```
find /home/goaccess/part/2/ -name '*.log' -exec cat {} + | goaccess - --log-format='%^ %dT%t.%^ %v %h:%^ %^ %^ %T %^ %s %^ %^ %b "%r" "%u" %k %K %^' -o /var/www/html/index.html --date-format=%Y-%m-%d --time-format=%T
```

As last resort: goaccess seem to support setting the input log file in the [configuration file](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/blob/9d4bab5dfab2de0dff39af95f12ee0eb983b3e90/config/goaccess.conf#L356C1-L356C1) but it is not clear if it can be more than one. If so you could generate a config file which includes all 28k log files.